# Show $\sum\limits_1 ^x \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} \sim x $

Tags: asymptotics

Assume $f(n)$ is defined over the positive integers with $$\sum_{1}^x f(n) \sim xg(x),$$ where $g$ is a differentiable function with $xg'(x) = o(g(x))$. I am having trouble showing that

> $$\sum_1 ^x \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} \sim x .$$

This doesn't seem to work for any differentiable function $g$ with the specified conditions, shouldn't $g$ also be positive? If so, how can we prove this statement?

Comment: Why is it tagged `number-theory`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Sketch:** As a heuristic step, let us consider the continuous case. Suppose
\begin{align}
\int^x_0 f(s)\ ds= xg(x)
\end{align}
then we see that
\begin{align}
f(x) = xg'(x)+g(x).
\end{align}
Then it follows
\begin{align}
\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 1+ \frac{xg'(x)}{g(x)}
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
\int^x_0 \frac{f(s)}{g(s)}\ ds = x+\int^x_0 \frac{s g'(s)}{g(s)}\ ds \sim Cx.
\end{align}
I have used the fact that when $x$ is sufficiently large
\begin{align}
\left|\frac{xg'(x)}{g(x)} \right| \leq \frac{1}{2}.
\end{align}

Now, make this work for the discrete case by using the Euler-Maclaurin formula.